# Disable/enable lan-device by batchfile: If comparisons not working

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, wmic

I have created this .bat-file which is invoked by clicking on the proper shortcut, which is configured properly.
But the last two comparisons seem not to evaluate properly.

Here we go.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 

SET landevcename='Imagine any name for a device'

SET landevcestatus=0
SET landevcestatusDisab=0
SET landevcestatusConn=2
SET landevcestatusT="NONE"
SET landevceidx=0

SET counter=1

ECHO Lan device to be checked is: %landevcename%

FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I IN ('wmic PATH win32_networkadapter where "Name=%landevcename%" get index')  DO ( 
        IF !counter!==2 SET /a landevceidx=%%I             

        SET /a counter+=1
     )
ECHO Index of local area connection is: %landevceidx%

SET /a counter=1
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%J IN ('wmic PATH win32_networkadapter where "Name=%landevcename%" get netconnectionstatus')  DO (       
                            IF !counter!==2 SET /a landevcestatus=%%J              

                            SET /a counter+=1
                           )

ECHO Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatus%                          

REM IF %landevcestatus%==%landevcestatusDisab% SET /a landevcestatusT=Disabled
IF %landevcestatus%==0 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsNotEnabled"

REM IF %landevcestatus%==%landevcestatusConn% SET /a landevcestatusT=Connected         
**IF %landevcestatus%==2 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsEnabled"**

ECHO Text - Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatusT%

ECHO Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatus%                          

CMD
@ECHO off
```

Those both:

**IF %landevcestatus%==0 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsNotEnabled"**

**IF %landevcestatus%==2 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsEnabled"**

Where could be the typo ?

Comment: Can you tell me the errors you are getting?

Comment: ECHO Text - Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatusT% is NONE.

Comment: Could you try setting an IF/ELSE rather than two separate FOR statements? It's seems a really complex routine for such a simple output. The problems are in the IF statements as it's only getting the variable you set at the start - ignoring everything else.

Comment: You mean instead of two seperate if's ? not for's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Where could be the typo?

- You have **many** errors in your batch file.
- You are clearly confused about how to use `set` and `set /a`. Please read [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).
- It would also be worth you reading [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php).
- A general observation - fix your indentation (it makes debugging easier).

---

#### Corrections

```
SET landevcename='Imagine any name for a device'
```

Should be:

```
SET landevcename="Imagine any name for a device"
```

If you use `'` then you need to escape the `'` in your `for` command.

---

```
IF !counter!==2 SET /a landevceidx=%%I
```

Should be:

```
IF !counter!==2 SET landevceidx=%%I
```

`/a` is used for numeric expressions **not** string assignments.

---

```
IF !counter!==2 SET /a landevcestatus=%%J
```

Should be:

```
IF !counter!==2 SET landevcestatus=%%J
```

---

```
SET /a counter+=1
```

Should be:

```
SET /a "counter+=1"
```

---

```
IF %landevcestatus%==0 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsNotEnabled"
```

Should be:

```
IF %landevcestatus%==0 SET landevcestatusT="ItIsNotEnabled"
```

---

```
IF %landevcestatus%==2 SET /a %landevcestatusT% "ItIsEnabled"
```

Should be:

```
IF %landevcestatus%==2 SET landevcestatusT="ItIsEnabled"
```

---

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I IN ('wmic PATH win32_networkadapter where "Name=%landevcename%" get index')  DO (
```

Should be:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I IN ('wmic PATH win32_networkadapter where Name^=%landevcename% get index')  DO (
```

You need to escape the `=` using `^`, and remove the `"`s (they are part of the variable `%landevcename%`).

---

#### Simplified batch file

You can do what you want with a single `for /f` command and fewer variables. You don't need an index or a counter.

Use the following batch file and set `landevicename` as appropriate.

**LanStatus.cmd**:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

set landevcename="Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device"

echo Lan device to be checked is: %landevcename%

rem skip first line
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i IN (`wmic PATH win32_networkadapter where Name^=%landevcename% get netconnectionstatus^, index ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`)  DO (  set landevceidx=%%i
  set landevcestatus=%%j       
  )

if %landevcestatus%==2 (
  set landevcestatusT="ItIsEnabled"
  ) else (
  set landevcestatusT="ItIsNotEnabled"
  )

echo Text - Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatusT%

echo Status of local area connection is: %landevcestatus%                        

echo Index of local area connection is: %landevceidx%

endlocal
```

**Example output**:

```
F:\test>lanstatus
Lan device to be checked is: "Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device"
Text - Status of local area connection is: "ItIsEnabled"
Status of local area connection is: 2
Index of local area connection is: 17
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: SET landevcename=Imagine any name for a device"

looks faulty. may be, forgot first quotes ?

Comment: Answer fixed ...

Comment: Did You also see, that sometimes /a is needed, afaik, because of the SetEnbleDelayesExpansion. I have it even from a SO site, partially ...

Comment: `/a` has nothing to do with `delayed expansion`. It is for arithmetic expressions. Please read the link I gave you.

Comment: Thanks once again, I have also been on that site some time, still kept the /a because it seemed to work mostly. Anyway, I will adopt the script as You recommended, and return with the results soon.

Comment: But  I have this tried before :
SET landevcename='"magine any name for a device"

This will fail in WMIC.

Comment: @icbytes There were more mistakes in your batch file. I'm adding a simplified batch file that works. Please wait a few minutes for me to update the answer.

Comment: Perfect, tiny, findtr properly used, I appreciate this.

Comment: One more thing. My usual aim, why I want to get the index is to either enable or disable it, like toggle.

Comment: Answer updated to save and echo `index`